# How do I assign the value of an element in an array to a variable and then assign that value to a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

I am creating an array, and once created I would like to be able to get the value of each element and put them into a cell. Whenever I try it seems that this is not possible to do.

```
Sub example()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim value As String


str = ("15,123,4")
arr = Split(str)
value = arr(1)
Range("M1").value = value



End Sub
```

I would like to be able to collect the values and put them into a cell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a delimiter for `Split`, viz `arr = Split(str, ",")`. By default it is space I think.

Comment: you can also skip the need for the variable `value` since you can set M1.value = arr(1)

Comment: Or just use `str = array(15,123,4)`.